# Memory map in Debuggers

Tags: assembly, memory, ollydbg

I opened an exe file compiled by Nasm in a debugger(x32dbg). In the memory map it shows where the program `section .text` and `section .data` starts.

1. How does it know.

Here is the code:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; helloworld.asm
;
; This is a Win32 console program that writes "Hello, World" on one line and
; then exits.  It needs to be linked with a C library.
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        global  _main
        extern  _printf

        section .text
_main:
        push    message
        call    _printf
        add     esp, 4
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

Comment: The executable metadata says what goes where in virtual memory; that's how the OS's program loader knows where to map it.  (With ASLR enabled, that's not fixed though.  I think the OS provides an API for debuggers to ask where stuff is mapped, or at least to examine the memory map of another process and see which file ranges are mapped where.  On Linux, you can see that for any process in `/proc/<PID>/smaps` but IDK about Windows, so I'm only commenting, not answering.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugger can find virtual address of program sections in portable-executable (PE) file.
Its structure is described in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms680547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?id=19509
You may inspect executables with some specialized tool, such as **PEview**.exe from
http://wjradburn.com/software/ 
, or look at the hexadecimal dump of your "helloworld.exe".

At file address (FA) 0x3C you will find DWORD with FA of **PE Header**, for instance 0x00000090=144.
Skip 144 bytes from the start of file and you should see DWORD **PEsignature** followed with 
20 bytes of **CoffFileHeader**. At 16.byte of CoffFileHeader there is WORD SizeOfOptionalHeader,
with value 0x00E0=224. This many bytes of **OptionalHeader** immediately follow the CoffFileHeader.
At offset 0xC4=196 in OptionalHeader there is DWORD field called **ImageBase** with VA where is the image
mapped in memory. Most linkers use ImageBase=0x00400000.

OptionaHeader is followed with **SectionHeader**s, one for each section used in the program.
Each SectionHeader is 40 bytes long, it contains SectionName in its first eight bytes, followed with section size rounded up to SectionAlignment, and followed with Relative Virtual Address (**RVA**) where the section starts. Usually the first section is the code section with Name=**.text**, Size=0x00001000 and RVA=0x00001000. 
RVA of each section is related to the ImageBase, so the .text section will be mapped at address **ImageBase+RVA=0x00401000**.
Which is the answer to your question.